# Can my ISP/MSP read my Whatsapp messages?

Tags: privacy

I wonder whether the Whatsapp messages are sufficiently encrypted so that the ISP/MSP ( mobile service provider) cannot read what is inside?

I will be travelling to some of the most oppressive regimes in the world, and I fear that my Whatsapp chats might be monitored because the messages will be passing through local ISPs or MSPs.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Short answer: **NO**, if you are sure you are using end to end encryption, and **MOST LIKELY NO**, if you aren't using end to end encryption.

Whatsapp uses encryption two ways: first it has an "outer layer" built by TLS, which has ben analyzed thoroughly by the security company [Praetorian](https://www.praetorian.com/blog/whats-up-with-whatsapps-security-facebook-ssl-vulnerabilities) in February 2014, with almost all issues pointed out being fixed within a day. The page only says that Whatsapp promised to include certificate pinning, but I assume they did in the meantime. If there is no certificate pinning, then ISPs/Governments with control over certificate authorities can indeed mount a successful MITM attack (and we know that china [did this](http://googleonlinesecurity.blogspot.de/2015/03/maintaining-digital-certificate-security.html)).

The second, inner layer, is more secure, when active. It uses the encryption used by [Textsecure](https://github.com/WhisperSystems/TextSecure/wiki/Protocol), and, if you have verified the keys of the the parties you communicate (e.g. by meeting them in person and comparing hashes), is quite secure (using modern standards, etc, but [without a professional review](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/43527)), once you know its activated. The activation part [is the problem](http://m.heise.de/ct/artikel/Keeping-Tabs-on-WhatsApp-s-Encryption-2630361.html): [you never actually know](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/79070/how-do-i-verify-that-whatsapp-is-using-end-to-end-encryption).

Also, according to [this answer](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/79096/52967), textsecure wasn't encrypted over 3G in the past.